# how to list currently active gesture recognizers?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I'd like to be able to list all currently active gesture recognizers (so I can temporarily disable them). Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the UIView's `gestureRecognizers` property:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.gestureRecognizers)
{
    //Do something with recognizer
}
```

More reading: [UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW102)

Comment: Note: If looking for if they are in an active state (currently being utilized by user's finger), you can check: `BOOL isGestureActive = (recognizer.state != 0);` However you can get a false positive if `.state` is `UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible`.  In which case you should then check `.numberOfTouches != 0`

Answer (score 2):

You could have a bool for your class and set it to ***TRUE*** when the recognizers has permission to do stuff. When you want to disable them you can set the bool to ***FALSE*** in your recognizer methods. You just have to test if the bool is true or false before doing the stuff that you need to.

Answer (score 2):

For some reasons this was hard for me to do in Swift so here is what ended up working.

```
var arrayOfGestureRecognizers: [UIGestureRecognizer] = self.topViewController.view.gestureRecognizers! as NSArray as [UIGestureRecognizer]

for item in arrayOfGestureRecognizers {
    println("Gesture Recognizer:\(item)")
}
```